# is there any way to add a new field in woocomerce order?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a field here, and that filed data should be asked while after the check out

[image]

I am using WordPress point of sale, i have tried a plugin to add custom field in checkout but i want a field that is a part of my order. 
I have 4 employees in my barber shop i want a field in order that allows me to put employees name, so that i can justify this order was placed by following customer and served my following employee

I have installed the plugin "Woo Checkout Field Editor Pro" put that field comes here in my Point of sale register

[image: This is the image where custom check out filed is coming]

but in my Point of sale that custom check out field once filled with a particular customer it remains the same for every order he places. I want a field that is filled each time every new order is place either it is for a guest or a register customer.

I want that custom field here so that it should be asked every time order is places 
[image: add custom field to order here]

Although I can do it manually by editing each order and adding a custom field form here the place where i can add a custom field by editing each order

[image: edit each order here] . But the problem is I don't want to do it manually I want it to ask every time I place the order

Comment: You're question is a little hard to understand. Please edit to provide more detail.

Comment: Have you thoroughly read my [customize checkout fields](https://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/) tutorial? From there you'd only need to add a custom column, which is also covered in plenty of tutorials on the web.

Comment: I have installed the plugin "Woo Checkout Field Editor Pro" but in my pos that costume check out field once filled with a particular customer it remains the same for every order he places. I want a field that is filled each time every new order is place either it is for a guest or a register customer.

Comment: @helgatheviking I have read your "my customize checkout filed tutorial", where do i add your code of "Add a Custom Checkout Field" I tried adding in functions.php of my current activated theme. But nothing happened.

Comment: Please insert the images rather than linking to them. It's easier for people to read that way. Anyway, my code *should* go in a plugin, but it works in functions.php. The difference is probably that you are using a POS and not default WooCommerce which I didn't know when I recommended you read my tutorial. You need to save your field as ORDER meta and not CUSTOMER meta, but I don't know anything about the POS plugin to advise. Good luck.

Comment: @helgatheviking Thanks alot your blog customize checkout filed helped me out. :)